# How do you make the command mode case insensitive?

Tags: command-line, letter-case

For example, I might accidentally type something like `:WQ` and I want it to work like `:wq` when a hit enter

Another case is where I am typing a longer command name, for example `NERDTreeTabsClose`. (Note that I have the settings ignorecase and smartcase set)

1. I might start by typing `:nerd` and then hitting tab, which will auto complete to `:NERDTree`
2. I might then type a little more so that the command mode shows `:NERDTreetab` and then I hit tab again.
3. Because I have smart case on, the auto complete will not work. The ideal scenario would be for the auto complete to work

I would like to keep smartcase on, because that is useful for searches with `/`.

Is there a way to achieve the behaviour have described above

Comment: for one-offs you might like https://github.com/vim-scripts/cmdalias.vim

Comment: except from creating alias commands in all different kind of spellings, not really possible

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can dynamically toggle smartcase using autocmds, so when in a `:` command line, it is off and when in a `/` command line it is on:

```
" assumes set ignorecase smartcase
augroup dynamic_smartcase
    autocmd!
    autocmd CmdLineEnter : set nosmartcase
    autocmd CmdLineLeave : set smartcase
augroup END
```

Answer (score 1):

I've personally found https://github.com/thinca/vim-ambicmd to be fairly useful for long commands.